# Can you critique my exposition of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt \pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Prove
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt \pi$$
using Fubini's Theorem.

My solution is below. Proof is Correct.

What I want to know is :
**Is it well written?

How could the writing be improved, made clearer, or more rigorous?**

---

Solution: We first show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left [e^{-y^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx \right ]dy = \pi.$$  By Fubini's Theorem, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left [e^{-y^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx \right ]dy = \iint_{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$ which, by changing to spherical coordinates, equals $$\begin{align*}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty re^{-r^2}dr d \theta &= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \Biggr|_0^\infty \frac {-e^{-r^2}}{2} d\theta\\ &=\pi.\end{align*}$$

Now, by linearity of integrals, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left [e^{-y^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx \right ]dy = \left [ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx  \right ] \left [ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}dy \right ]$$ and since  $e^{-x^2} > 0$ for all $x$, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt \pi$$ as desired.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started editing the Question to "improve" it & then realized that OP is actually asking what "improvements" to make & that should come in the Answer. Hence I left it as-is after the "divider line" & will make my suggestions here.

Proof is well-written & well-known & rigorous enough.
It could be improved to make it slightly clearer what the aim is & what the method is.
There are no tags , to refer to later.
There is a slight non-linearity [ "roundaboutness" ] in Presentation.
There is no variable to capture the Integral value , which we can use to refer later.

Here is my way to write it out :

---

Let
$$ P = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2} dx \tag{1.1} $$

$$ P^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2} dx \times \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2} dy \tag{1.2} $$

By linearity of Integrals ,

$$ P^2 = \left [ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx  \right ] \left [ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}dy \right ] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left [e^{-y^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx \right ]dy \tag{1.3} $$

By the Fubini Theorem ,
$\cdots\text{ skipping the calculations given by OP , to be written with few tags where necessary }\cdots$

$$ P^2 = \pi \tag{2.1} $$

Since the Exponential is Positive ,
$$ P = \sqrt{\pi} \tag{2.2} $$

We have the necessary Conclusion :

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi} \tag{2.3} $$

**QED**

---

When we have other further work involving that Integral , we can easily refer to $(2.3)$

Here is the Image to high-light what changes I made to eliminate the "roundaboutness" :

[image: non-linearity]